# search first element of a multivalue text field in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to search first element of array in documents of elasticsearch, but I can't.

I don't find it that how can I search.

For test, I created new index with fielddata=true, but I still didn't get the response that I wanted

Document

```
      "name" : {
        "type" : "text",
        "fields" : {
          "keyword" : {
            "type" : "keyword",
            "ignore_above" : 256
          }
        }
      },
```

Values

> name : ["John", "Doe"]

My request

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : {
                "script" : {
                    "script" : {
                        "source": "doc['name'][0]=params.param1",
                                                "params" : {
                            "param1" : "john"
                        }
                     }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Incoming Response

```
"reason": "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default. Set fielddata=true on [name] in order to load fielddata in memory by uninverting the inverted index. Note that this can however use significant memory. Alternatively use a keyword field instead."
```

Comment: Did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the following script that is used in a search request to return a [scripted field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-using.html):**

```
{
  "script_fields": {
    "firstElement": {
      "script": {
        "lang":   "painless",
        "inline": "params._source.name[0]"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "stof_64391432",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "fields": {
          "firstElement": [
            "John"             <-- note this
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

**You can use a [Painless script to create a script field to return a customized value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-field-context.html) for each document in the results of a query.**

> You need to use [equality equals](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-operators-boolean.html#equality-equals-operator) operator '==' to COMPARE two
> values where the resultant boolean type value is true if the two
> values are equal and false otherwise in the script query.

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings":{
    "properties":{
      "name":{
        "type":"text",
        "fielddata":true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index data:**

```
{
  "name": [
    "John",
    "Doe"
  ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "script_fields": {
    "my_field": {
      "script": {
        "lang":   "painless",
        "source": "params['_source']['name'][0] == params.params1",
        "params": {
          "params1": "John"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "fields": {
          "my_field": [
            true                  <-- note this
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, your solutions isn't enough for me. because i want to use filter and exact match with prefix search.

Comment: @ecavusoglu why do you want to have prefix search over here ? Can you please explain your use case more clearly ?

Comment: let me explain like this, i want to name search for booking documents at elasticsearch. i have "name" column with various columns. if i getting name query in  get request, i append match query for name to query like this {"query":{"match":{"name":{"query":"john doe","operator":"and"}}}}

i have multiple names in name columns in document. "name": ["John Doe","Doe Williams"]. Just I want to search first element of array. i just looking how can I do it

Comment: okay @ecavusoglu if I understood correctly, then you are searching whether a given name (in your case john doe) is present at the beginning of the name array or not? And if it is there, then only you want to return the document?

Comment: @ecavusoglu can you please share your expected search result also ?

Comment: of course, {"booking_id":1,"name":["John Doe","David John"],...},{"booking_id":2,"name":["John Doe","Adam Simith"],...}

Answer (score 0):

> [Arrays of objects](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) do not work as you would expect: you cannot query
> each object independently of the other objects in the array. If you
> need to be able to do this then you should use the nested data type
> instead of the object data type.

**You can use the script as shown in my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64391525/10348758) if you want to just compare the value of the first element of the array to some other value.** But based on your comments, it looks like your use case is quite different.

If you want to search the first element of the array you need to convert your data, into nested form. **Using arrays of object at search time you can’t refer to “the first element” or “the last element”.**

Adding a working example with index data, mapping, search query, and search result

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "booking_id": 2,
  "name": [
    {
      "first": "John Doe",
      "second": "abc"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "booking_id": 1,
  "name": [
    {
      "first": "Adam Simith",
      "second": "John Doe"
    }
  ]
}
{
  "booking_id": 3,
  "name": [
    {
      "first": "John Doe",
      "second": "Adam Simith"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "name",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match_phrase": {
                "name.first": "John Doe"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.9400072,
        "_source": {
          "booking_id": 2,
          "name": [
            {
              "first": "John Doe",
              "second": "abc"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.9400072,
        "_source": {
          "booking_id": 3,
          "name": [
            {
              "first": "John Doe",
              "second": "Adam Simith"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: @ecavusoglu I have added another answer because it is a completely different approach. Please go through my answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue :)

Comment: @ecavusoglu it's been a long time. I hope you are doing well :) Did you get a chance to go through my answer, looking forward to get feedback from you 